# Arduino for loop

Tags: arduino-uno

I am a beginner in Arduino programming. This is my program for 5 LEDs and 1 Button. The LEDs are supposed to light before I press the button. But the LEDs start immediately, even without pressing the button. How is it possible?

```
int sw7=7;
int timer=500;
int start=0;
int stopp=100;
void setup()
{
  for (int opin=1;opin<6;opin++)
  {
    pinMode(opin,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(sw7,INPUT);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead (sw7)==LOW)
  {
    while (start<=stopp);
  }
  {
    for (int opin=1;opin<=5;opin++)
    {
      digitalWrite(opin,HIGH);
      delay(timer);
      digitalWrite(opin,LOW);
     } 
  }
}
```

Comment: how did you wire the button? has it pull-down?

Comment: It's a large tack switch. 1 foot is on pin 7 in series with the other foot connected to 5v and the foot beside the foot that is connected in pin 7 is connected to ground. Is there nothing wrong with the program? Thank you.

Comment: I aligned your code. do you see how the `for` loop is outside of the `if` for the button?

Comment: no resistor? wire it this way and use mode INPUT_PULLUP https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/InputPullupSerial

Comment: try putting an `else` between `}
  {`

Comment: @Juraj there is a resistor. I think it's there something wrong with the code.

Comment: @Juraj okay I'll wire it. I'll get back to you, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gerben. void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead (sw7)==LOW)
  {
    while (start<=stopp);
  }
else  
{
    for (int opin=1;opin<=5;opin++)
    {

like this?

Comment: How are the LEDs wired? +5 to anode, cathode to resistor, resistor to pin?  If so, then they turn on with a low output, and probably turn on right after the pinMode command.  Try a test - add a noticeable delay after the pinMode, see if that's when turn on. If so, then drive the outputs high after the pinMode to 'initialize' them, and change your code to turn them on with a Low instead of High.   Also, using INPUT_PULLUP on the switch and testing for a Low instead of a High will keep the switch input from floating around when it is not pressed.

Comment: why are you running this 5 times? `pinMode(sw7,INPUT);`

Comment: these two are the same thing `The LEDs are supposed to light before I press the button.` and `LEDs start immediately` ...... i think that you need to edit your question

Comment: Your line  `while (start<=stopp);` will put your sketch into an infinite loop. `start` will always be less than `stopp`, so that loop will never end and your program will freeze once it begins executing that `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Several things:

You need to explicitly set your output pins to `LOW` in your setup method.

The code to set the sw7 to input should not be inside the loop.

You should probably connect your switch between sw7 and ground and use `INPUT_PULLUP` mode (in `INPUT_PULLUP` mode the line is connected to +5V through a "pull-up resistor" so that it reads HIGH until you press the button, and then it reads LOW. If you don't use either an input pull-up or pull-down resistor then the input tends to "float" and give bad readings.)

You say "The LEDs are supposed to light before I press the button. But the LEDs start immediately, even without pressing the button."

I'm not sure what you mean. What do you want to happen, exactly? Do you want the LEDs to be lit steadily, and then turn off or flash when you press the button?

The code below will turn off all the LEDs initially, then toggle between off and flashing on each (debounced) button press. Switch the value of `idleLEDState` to HIGH if you want the LEDs to be lit when they are not flashing.

```
#define flashDelay 50 //Delay between on and off state for LEDs
#define switchBounceDelay 100


uint8_t idleLEDState = LOW; //Change to HIGH 
                            //if you want the LEDs to be lit when not flashing
bool flashLEDs = false;
bool ledsOn = false; 
unsigned long nextFlashTime = 0;
unsigned long nextSwitchCheckTime = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(sw7, INPUT_PULLUP); //Connect the switch between sw7 and ground
  for (int opin=1;opin<6;opin++)
  {
    pinMode(opin,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(opin, idleLEDState); 
  }
}

void loop() {

  //If it's time to check the switch, and it's being pulled LOW, toggle flashLEDs
  if (mills() > nextSwitchCheckTime && digitalRead(sw7) == LOW) {
    flashLEDs = !flashLEDs;
    nextSwitchCheckTime = millis() + switchBounceDelay;
  }

  if (!flashLEDs) {
    //IF we're not supposed to flash the LEDs, set them to their idle state 
    for (int opin=1;opin<6;opin++) {
        digitalWrite(opin, idleLEDState); 
     }
  } else if millis() > nextFlashTime {
    nextTime = millis() + flashDelay;
    ledsOn = !ledsOn;
    for (int opin=1;opin<6;opin++) {
        uint8_t newState = ledsOn ? HIGH : LOW;
        digitalWrite(opin, newState); 
     }
}
```

I banged out the code above in the Stack Exchange editor. It likely contains a few typos. Please exert some effort to fix it and adapt it to your needs before posting back "Your code didn't work. I got error XYZ."

Answer (score 0):

This is a sketch according to your requirements:

```
// pin mapping
int pin_map[] = { 
  1,  // 0: led in pin 1
  2,  // 1: led in pin 2
  3,  // 2: led in pin 3
  4,  // 3: led in pin 4 
  5,  // 4: led in pin 5
  7   // 5: button (pull-up)
};

int timeout_ms = 500;
int blink_ms = 100;

void setup()
{
  // setup pins
  for (int opin = 0; opin < 5; opin++) pinMode(pin_map[opin], OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_map[5], INPUT_PULLUP);

  // wait for activation
  while (millis() < timeout_ms)
  {
    // activate by button (off:pull-up on:GND)
    if (digitalRead (pin_map[5]) == LOW) break;
  }
}


void loop()
{
  for (int opin = 0; opin < 5; opin++) 
  {
    // toggle LED
    int pin = pin_map[opin];
    pinMode(pin, !digitalRead(pin));
  }

  delay(blink_ms);
}
```

You will need avoid delay() usage if you need asynchronous tasks. Probably, you should study C language and practice with some hundred of sketchs to improve your code skills.

Comment: Putting the LED pins and the switch pins into the same array seems confusing. They do different things. I do see the value in using an array to store the LED pin assignments though. That way you can use any pins for the LEDs, even discontinuous pin numbers.